# How can MongoDB WriteConcernResult Be mocked?

Tags: c#, mongodb, unit-testing, mocking, rhino-mocks

I am trying to mock a `WriteConcernResult` returned via an `Insert()`;

A `WriteConcernResult` is returned by my provider and the `Insert()` is called via Add User:

```
private readonly IMongoProvider _repository;

public UserRepository(IMongoProvider repository)
{
    _repository = repository.ForCollection("User");
}

public bool AddUser(UserModel user)
{
    var result = _repository.Insert(user);
    return result.DocumentsAffected > 0;
}
```

The MongoDB `WriteConcernResult` class:

```
public WriteConcernResult(BsonDocument response)
{
    _response = Ensure.IsNotNull(response, nameof(response));
}

public long DocumentsAffected
{
    get
    {
        BsonValue value;
        return _response.TryGetValue("n", out value) ? value.ToInt64() : 0;
    }
}
```

Because `DocumentsAffected` does not have a setter I am unsure how to set a value my mock will return.

```
{
    var user = new UserModel {Name = "Test"};

    _mockMongoProvider = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IMongoProvider>();

     //mock writeConcernResult

     var result = _repo.AddUser(user);
     Assert.That(result, Is.True);
}
```

With a setter I would likely mock like this:

```
_mockMongoProvider.Stub(p => p.Insert(user))
                  .Return(new WriteConcernResult(
                                                    new BsonDocument()
                                                ).DocumentsAffected = 1);
```

Any guidance would be very helpful, cheers.

Comment: Have you tried my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you don't need to mock the `WriteConcernResult` class at all.

All you have to do is to initialize an instance of `WriteConcernResult` as the following:

```
var document = new BsonDocument();
document.Add("n", new BsonInt64(1));
var writeConcernResult = new WriteConcernResult(document);
```

Then you'll have to setup your mock repository to return this instance:

```
_mockMongoProvider.Stub(p => p.Insert(user))
                  .Return(writeConcernResult );
```